# Pandas - Problema Groupby seguido de otras operaciones

Tags: python, pandas

Inicialmente tengo los siguientes DFs (llamados frutas_df y gastos_df respectivamente):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el primero se representa la cantidad de fruta adquirida y en el otro el gasto en cada adquisición. Con este último hago un groupby (llamado total_gasto_df), obteniendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente, quiero dividir el gasto entre las cantidades adquiridas para obtener el precio/ud introduciendo lo siguiente:

***total_gasto_df['Ratio'] = total_gasto_df['Gasto'] / frutas_df['Cantidad']***

Sin embargo, obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que tiene problemas para operar con la columna surgida del groupby, pero necesitaría ayuda sobre cómo solucionarlo de la manera más eficiente posible.

Answer (score 0):

Reinicia el índice del dataframe `total_gasto_df` y con eso ya calcularía correctamente el ratio:

```
total_gasto_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Reinicio el índice y cuando voy a calcular el ratio me salta el siguiente error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta y agrega el código completo.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de agrupar...

total_gasto_df2=total_gasto_df.reset_index()

**Obtendras un df llamado total_gasto_df2**

total_gasto_df['Ratio'] = total_gasto_df2['Gasto'] / frutas_df['Cantidad']

A mi me ha ocurrido en ocasiones que el groupby necesita un *reset_index*, a ver si te funciona :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los dataframes que divides entre sí no tienen los mismos índices, por lo que pandas no sabe qué fila ha de ser dividida entre qué otra fila del otro datframe.

Voy a comenzar por replicar tu dataset para mostrarlo:

```
import pandas as pd

frutas_df = pd.DataFrame({"Tipo": ["Manzana", "Plátano"],
                          "Cantidad": [210, 390]})
gastos_df = pd.DataFrame({"Tipo": ["Manzana", "Manzana", "Plátano", "Plátano"],
                          "Gasto": [80, 60, 74, 56]})
total_gasto_df = gastos_df.groupby("Tipo").sum()
```

Ahora vemos que `total_gasto_df` tiene como índice el Tipo (los nombres de las frutas):

```
         Gasto
Tipo          
Manzana    140
Plátano    130
```

y sin embargo `frutas_db` tiene como índice una secuencia de números, pues el tipo de fruta es una columna más:

```
      Tipo  Cantidad
0  Manzana       210
1  Plátano       390
```

(el índice es 0, 1, ...)

y por esa razón no se pueden dividir.

### Soluciones

Hay dos opciones:

1. Resetear el índice de `total_gasto_df` para que también sean números, y tras eso ya se puede hacer la división:

   ```
   >>> total_gasto_df.reset_index().Gasto/frutas_df.Cantidad
   0    0.666667
   1    0.333333
   dtype: float64
   ```
2. Hacer que en `frutas_df` el índice sea el tipo de fruta, coincidiendo así con el índice de `total_gasto_df`, lo que permite también hacer la división:

   ```
   >>> total_gasto_df.Gasto/frutas_df.set_index("Tipo").Cantidad
   Tipo
   Manzana    0.666667
   Plátano    0.333333
   dtype: float64
   ```

Encuentro preferible el segundo caso por dos razones:

- En el resultado podemos ver los nombres de las frutas, pues están en el índice del resultado (y eso le permite a pandas asignarlo a las filas correctas cuando haces la asignación `total_gasto_df[Ratio] = ...`
- El matching de qué fila hay que dividir por cuál otra se hace en base al index, y por tanto en base al nombre de la fruta. En la primera solución estaríamos dependiendo de que las frutas salgan listadas en el mismo orden en ambos dataframes, lo que no tiene por qué ser así.

Comment: Gracias por la solución! Ahora el problema que me planteo es: si necesito realizar un join con un tercer DF independiente y necesito el campo de tipo de fruta para hacer la unión, ya no podría hacerlo porque ya no la tendría como columna sino como índice. ¿Qué podría hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Puedes hacer un `.reset_index()` en el dataframe del resultado. Eso elimina el tipo del índice y lo deja de nuevo como columna (creando un nuevo índice autonumerado).

Comment: He probado y (creo) que se puede hacer el join manteniendo la columna como índice, siempre que en el otro DF haya una columna igual a dicho índice.